# How do I find a matrix representation of a linear transformation with two bases?

Tags: linear-transformations

I've seen other examples of how to do this, but I still can't seem to figure this question out:

[image: This is the question.]

I believe I am supposed to plug the elements of the basis alpha into the transformation to see which coefficients of beta it is in terms of, using these as the columns for the vector.
My attempts at this so far have been unsuccessful, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for some weird reason people struggle greatly with this. And yet, the algorithm is extremely simple: if $T:V \to W$ is a linear map and $V$ and $W$ have (ordered) bases $B$ and $C$, you

(1) evaluate $T$ at the $j$th element of $B$;

(2) write the result as a linear combination of the elements in $C$;

(3) place the coefficients of this combination in the $j$th column of a matrix.

This matrix is $[T]_{B,C}$.

Comment: So in this case, f could be represented by the equation bx + c as it is a polynomial of degree 1 or less. Therefore, for the value 1 in the basis alpha, I would be transforming b(1) + c, giving me (b + c, b + c) when transformed. I'm still not sure how I could write this as a linear combination of the elements in beta? The same goes for the value x in alpha, where the transformation result is (b + c, 2b + c). Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: What is the confusion? If $f(x)=bx+c$, then $f(1)=b+c$ and $f(2)=2b+c$. So $$T(bx+c) = (b+c,2b+c).$$Read everything very slowly and carefully.

Comment: Can you write $T(1)=(1,1)$ and $T(x)= (1,2)$ as linear combinations of the standard basis in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I now realise I was being silly. So T(1) could be written as a combination of (1,0) + (0,1) and T(x) writen as (1,0) + 2(0,1). Hence our matrix would be (1,1) on the top and (1,2) on the bottom?

Comment: Replace "row" with "column" everywhere in your last comment and yes. See step (3) of the algorithm again.

Comment: Oh yes my bad. Thank you very much for the help. :)